# Why is the unit of my time difference inconsistent when calculated within ifelse() on a grouped dataframe?

Tags: r, datetime, dplyr

I'm calculating a conditional time difference between 2 columns, can someone please explain why in the first row it's returned in seconds, and in the third row it's returned in minutes? The data frame is grouped by `group`.

```
library(dplyr)

source <- data.frame(
  group = c(1,1,2),
  start = as.POSIXct(c("2023-12-01 00:00:00", "2023-12-01 00:01:00", "2023-12-01 00:00:00")),
  end = as.POSIXct(c("2023-12-01 00:01:00", "2023-12-01 00:01:00", "2023-12-01 00:01:00")),
  boolean_flag = c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE)
)

reprex <- source %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(length = ifelse(boolean_flag, end - start, 0)) %>%
  ungroup()

reprex
```

[image: screenshot of the reprex dataframe]

I am aware that the problem would no longer appear if I switch to `if_else()` instead, or if I use `difftime()` with `unit="mins"` specified instead of a simple substraction, I am here however trying to understand why this is happening with the current code. The problem also disappears if the second row where the end is the same as the start is removed.

**Edit:**

As both answers below pointed out, with this code the unit is group specific, and it will be set to accommodate the smallest value present within the group.

This is clear with the below updated `source` data frame which also has records which are 1 day and 1 hour apart:

```
source <- data.frame(
  group = c(1,1,2,3,3,4),
  start = as.POSIXct(c("2023-12-01 00:00:00", "2023-12-01 00:01:00", "2023-12-01 00:00:00", "2023-12-01 00:00:00", "2023-12-01 00:00:00", "2023-12-01 00:00:00")),
  end = as.POSIXct(c("2023-12-01 00:01:00", "2023-12-01 00:01:00", "2023-12-01 00:01:00", "2023-12-02 00:00:00", "2023-12-01 01:00:00", "2023-12-01 01:00:00")),
  boolean_flag = c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE)
)
```

[image]

Unit of each group:

- Group 1: seconds (set by the second row)
- Group 2: minutes
- Group 3: hours (set by the fifth row)
- Group 4: days

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When subtracting times, `difftime` is dispatched, which tries to be "pretty" rather than having a default for units. If using `difftime` directly you can set units. This is nothing entirely specific to your code, but apparently `difftime` is applied on each group separately so `group_by` is the culprit and each group gets their own unit.

```
> reprex <- source %>%
+   group_by(group) %>%
+   mutate(length = ifelse(boolean_flag, difftime(end, start, units='secs'), 0)) %>%
+   ungroup()
> reprex
# A tibble: 3 × 5
  group start               end                 boolean_flag length
  <dbl> <dttm>              <dttm>              <lgl>         <dbl>
1     1 2023-12-01 00:00:00 2023-12-01 00:01:00 TRUE             60
2     1 2023-12-01 00:01:00 2023-12-01 00:01:00 TRUE              0
3     2 2023-12-01 00:00:00 2023-12-01 00:01:00 TRUE             60
```

May I assume, your real code is more complex, or why do you need grouping for calculating time difference for *each* row?

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply! "`difftime` is applied on each group separately so `group_by` is the culprit and each group gets their own unit": this behaviour seems a bit dangerous, I'll make sure next time to avoid "raw" time subtraction in `ifelse()`!

And yes indeed, the real code is far more complex as I'm doing calculations on the `length` value with other lagged variables which is where grouping is required. This was just a minimal reproducible example to show the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Basically the formatting changes per group. When it 'sees' the zero value it dynamically adjusts the output format.

A workaround can be to use `as.duration` from `lubridate`

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

source %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  mutate(length = ifelse(boolean_flag, as.duration(end - start), 0)) %>%
  ungroup()
# A tibble: 3 × 5
  group start               end                 boolean_flag length
  <dbl> <dttm>              <dttm>              <lgl>         <dbl>
1     1 2023-12-01 00:00:00 2023-12-01 00:01:00 TRUE             60
2     1 2023-12-01 00:01:00 2023-12-01 00:01:00 TRUE              0
3     2 2023-12-01 00:00:00 2023-12-01 00:01:00 TRUE             60
```

Comment: It seems indeed that whenever a zero is present in the group the output will automatically turn to seconds. If I change the last `end` value to `"2023-12-02 00:00:00"` the `length` will still return 1, but it would mean 1 **day** in this case rather than 1 **minute** like before. I would have expected the output to be consistent, but in this case `as.duration()` seems to be needed as you rightly pointed out if I want to keep the rest of my code unchanged.